# Why @PostConstruct in spring will retry silently on runtime exception?

Tags: java, spring

According to the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) `@PostConstruct` **MUST NOT throw application exception**, but does not discuss runtime exception. Meanwhile, the spring documentation also does not mention what the behavior would be in this situation.

I have a code like this

```
@Component
public class A{

   @Autowired
   private B b;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      logger.info("Post construsting");
      throw new RuntimeException("runtime exception!");
   }
}
```

Then the log will show **Post Construsting** 10 times before throw out that exception. I wondered why `@PostConstruct` will retry silently? Could something be wrong in my configuration/code?

Comment: Well show the configutration...  You probalby have more beans that all require a dependency on A. While construction of that fails it probably move on the the next bean until it is certain it cannot do anything anymore.